PyQt5 override AcceptDrops = False blockade of Drag Events
I've the following code :
main.py :
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

from myui_bis import Ui_Form 

    

class MainWidget(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.printAcceptDrops)
        
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.printScrollBars)
        
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.setAcceptDropsTrue)
        
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.setAcceptDropsFalse)
        
        
        # self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setAcceptDrops(False) #rtry uncommenting it
        
        
        # self.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.ForbiddenCursor))
        
        
        self.show()
        


    def setAcceptDropsTrue(self):
        
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.acceptDrops())       
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.acceptDrops()) 
        
        
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(True)     
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(True)    
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(True)     
        
        
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.acceptDrops())       
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.acceptDrops()) 
        
        
    def setAcceptDropsFalse(self):
        
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.acceptDrops())       
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.acceptDrops()) 
        
        
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(False)   
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(False)
        
        
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.acceptDrops())       
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.acceptDrops()) 
        

        
    def printAcceptDrops(self):
        
        print('printAcceptDrops : ')


        print('Mainwidget : ', self.acceptDrops())

        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.acceptDrops())       
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.acceptDrops()) 
        
    
    def printScrollBars(self):
        
        self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().maximum())
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWidget()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


my mywidgets.py :


from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QWidget, QScrollArea

from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag, QPixmap, QCursor

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData, QTimer


class MyLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    
    def __init__(self , parent = None):
        super(MyLineEdit, self).__init__(parent)
        
        
        self.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))
    
    
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        
        e.accept()
        
        
    def dropEvent(self, e):
        
        
        widget = e.source()
        
        print('\n dropped on widget !!!!!!!!!!!!\n\n')
        
        
        if widget == self :
            
            return
        
        
        if widget.parent().layout().count() == 1:
            
            print('=============== 1   qlineedit')
            
            widget.parent().layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(True)
        
       
        widget.setParent(None)
        
        
        self.parent().layout().insertWidget(self.parent().layout().indexOf(self) , widget)
        
        
    
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):

        if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mime = QMimeData()
            drag.setMimeData(mime)

            pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
            self.render(pixmap)
            drag.setPixmap(pixmap)

            drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)
            
            
            
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self , parent = None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.timer =  QTimer()
        
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda timer = self.timer : self.update_ScrollBar(timer))
        
        self.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.ForbiddenCursor))
        
        
    
    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        
        # self.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.ForbiddenCursor))
         
        self.timer.start(100) # time in milliseconds.
        
        e.accept()
        
    def dragLeaveEvent(self , e) :
        
        
        # self.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))
    
        print('DRAG LEAVED !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
        
        self.timer.stop()
    
        print('TIMER STOPPED')
    
    
    def update_ScrollBar(self , timer):
        
        coords = self.parent().rect().getRect()
        
        yup = coords[1]
        
        ydown = coords[1]+coords[3]
        
        ycurs =  self.parent().mapFromGlobal(QCursor().pos()).y() ####  OK

        
        if abs(yup - ycurs) < 80 :
            
            print(abs(yup - ycurs) , yup , ycurs)
            
            self.parent().parent().verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.parent().parent().verticalScrollBar().value() - 80)
            
            timer.stop()
            
        elif abs(ydown - ycurs) < 80 :
            
            self.parent().parent().verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.parent().parent().verticalScrollBar().value() + 80)
            
            timer.stop()
        
        else:
        
            timer.stop()
            
            print('TIMER STOPPED')

    
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        
        
        # self.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.ForbiddenCursor))
        
        
        print('ENTER DRAG EVENT IN ', self.objectName())
        
        print('self.layout.count()', self.layout().count())
        
        e.accept()
        
        
    def dropEvent(self, e):
        
        widget = e.source()
        
        
        if widget.parent().layout().count() == 1:
            
            print('=============== 1   WIDGET')
            
            widget.parent().layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(True)
            
        
        if self.layout().count() == 0 :
            
            
            widget.setParent(None)
            
            self.layout().addWidget(widget)
            
            self.setAcceptDrops(False)
            
        else :
              
            print('not dropped right !!!!!!!!!!!!')
            
 
class MyScrollArea(QScrollArea):
    
    def __init__(self , parent = None):
        super(MyScrollArea, self).__init__(parent)


my PyQt5-Designer ui file translated with pyuic5 myui_bis :
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(757, 708)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Form.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        Form.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        Form.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.scrollArea_4 = MyScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea_4.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea_4.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_4.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_4.setObjectName("scrollArea_4")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4 = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 344, 302))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_4")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(-1, 30, -1, 30)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(30)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.scrollArea_4.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_4, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea = MyScrollArea(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollArea.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollArea.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollArea.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 345, 945))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(-1, 30, -1, 30)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(30)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.lineEdit_1 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_1.setObjectName("lineEdit_1")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.lineEdit_3 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3)
        self.lineEdit_4 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4)
        self.lineEdit_5 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_5)
        self.lineEdit_15 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_15.setObjectName("lineEdit_15")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_15)
        self.lineEdit_14 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_14.setObjectName("lineEdit_14")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_14)
        self.lineEdit_13 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_13.setObjectName("lineEdit_13")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_13)
        self.lineEdit_12 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_12.setObjectName("lineEdit_12")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_12)
        self.lineEdit_11 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_11.setObjectName("lineEdit_11")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_11)
        self.lineEdit_10 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_10.setObjectName("lineEdit_10")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_10)
        self.lineEdit_9 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName("lineEdit_9")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_9)
        self.lineEdit_8 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_8)
        self.lineEdit_7 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_7)
        self.lineEdit_6 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea_2 = MyScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea_2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_2.setObjectName("scrollArea_2")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 344, 302))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_2")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(-1, 30, -1, 30)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(30)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea_3 = MyScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea_3.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_3.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_3.setObjectName("scrollArea_3")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3 = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 345, 302))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(-1, 30, -1, 30)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(30)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.scrollArea_3.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.lineEdit_1.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(_translate("Form", "2"))
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(_translate("Form", "3"))
        self.lineEdit_4.setText(_translate("Form", "4"))
        self.lineEdit_5.setText(_translate("Form", "5"))
        self.lineEdit_15.setText(_translate("Form", "6"))
        self.lineEdit_14.setText(_translate("Form", "7"))
        self.lineEdit_13.setText(_translate("Form", "8"))
        self.lineEdit_12.setText(_translate("Form", "9"))
        self.lineEdit_11.setText(_translate("Form", "10"))
        self.lineEdit_10.setText(_translate("Form", "11"))
        self.lineEdit_9.setText(_translate("Form", "12"))
        self.lineEdit_8.setText(_translate("Form", "13"))
        self.lineEdit_7.setText(_translate("Form", "14"))
        self.lineEdit_6.setText(_translate("Form", "15"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "ScrollBar 1 Maximum"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Check AcceptDrops"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Set AcceptDrops True"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Set AcceptDrops False"))

from mywidgets import MyLineEdit, MyScrollArea, MyWidget

I am trying to have the MyLineEdit (QLineEdit) dragging on the ScrollArea to move the VerticalScrollBar present on each of the 4 ScrollAreas. At th same time I need to prevent Dropping of the MyLineEdit on the empty parts ofthe ScrollAreas but accept them only on top of other MyLine widgets. I resolved to set the AcceptDrops attribute of my empty SrollAreas to True to accept the first Drop and the to move it to False to allow Drops only on already present MyLineEdit widgets. Now I am facing this problem (not able to find any solution with google or here on SO):
setting ScrollArea widgets AcceptDrops = False prevents them accepting DragEnter and DragMoveEvent , to the latter Event I attached the ability to change the VerticalScrollBar value so to move it while dragging my widgets.
Is there any solution to allow my script to have my ScrollAreaWidgetContents AcceptDrops = False but at the same time allow the Drag Events (Enter and Move not DropEvent of course) on them ?
You can test this behaviour by setting the AcceptDrop False/True via the two QPusButtons at the bottom of the main widget:


guess I'l have to keep  AcceptDrops = True and work on the dragEnterEvent , dragMoveEvent and DropEvent to adjust every widget to my desiderata
